# Concatenate Time Ranges with multiple rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

on SQL Server, I got a view returning the following employee data. As you see, it shows 3 adjacent time slots (columns `From` and `Till`).

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| PerNr    | Name       | From       | Till       | CostCentre | RowNumber | Percentage |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 12345678 | Marco Polo | 2015-12-07 | 2015-12-09 | Centre1    |         1 |        0.5 |
| 12345678 | Marco Polo | 2015-12-07 | 2015-12-09 | Centre2    |         2 |        0.2 |
| 12345678 | Marco Polo | 2015-12-07 | 2015-12-09 | Centre3    |         3 |        0.3 |
| 12345678 | Marco Polo | 2015-12-10 | 2015-12-13 | Centre1    |         1 |        0.5 |
| 12345678 | Marco Polo | 2015-12-10 | 2015-12-13 | Centre2    |         2 |        0.2 |
| 12345678 | Marco Polo | 2015-12-10 | 2015-12-13 | Centre3    |         3 |        0.3 |
| 12345678 | Marco Polo | 2015-12-14 | 2015-12-16 | Centre1    |         1 |        0.6 |
| 12345678 | Marco Polo | 2015-12-14 | 2015-12-16 | Centre2    |         2 |        0.1 |
| 12345678 | Marco Polo | 2015-12-14 | 2015-12-16 | Centre3    |         3 |        0.3 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Now I want to combine the blocks where the data (everything except PerNr, From and Till) doesn't change. The result should look like the following (notice the first and second set of 3 rows is now combined):

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| PerNr    | Name       | From       | Till       | CostCentre | RowNumber | Percentage |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 12345678 | Marco Polo | 2015-12-07 | 2015-12-13 | Centre1    |         1 |        0.5 |
| 12345678 | Marco Polo | 2015-12-07 | 2015-12-13 | Centre2    |         2 |        0.2 |
| 12345678 | Marco Polo | 2015-12-07 | 2015-12-13 | Centre3    |         3 |        0.3 |
| 12345678 | Marco Polo | 2015-12-14 | 2015-12-16 | Centre1    |         1 |        0.6 |
| 12345678 | Marco Polo | 2015-12-14 | 2015-12-16 | Centre2    |         2 |        0.1 |
| 12345678 | Marco Polo | 2015-12-14 | 2015-12-16 | Centre3    |         3 |        0.3 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

What I tried so far is running the following statements:

```
SELECT result1.pernr, result1.name, result1.[from], result1.till, result1.costcentre, result1.rownumber, result1.percentage
INTO #concatenated
FROM #result result1
INNER JOIN #result result2 ON
    (result1.pernr = result2.pernr) AND
    (
        (DATEADD(day, -1, result1.[from]) = t3.till OR
        (DATEADD(day, -1, result1.[from]) = t2.till)
    ) AND
    result1.rn = result2.rn and
    result1.costcentre = result2.costcentre and
    result1.rownumber = result2.rownumber and
    result1.percentage = result2.percentage
;

-- Join using GROUP BY
SELECT t2.pernr, t2.name, min(t2.[from]) from, max(t2.till) till, t2.costcentre, t2.rownumber, t2.percentage
FROM #concatenated t2
GROUP BY t2.pernr, t2.name, t2.costcentre, t2.rownumber, t2.percentage;

-- Find and add all not yet matched
INSERT INTO #concatenated2
SELECT t1.pernr, t1.name, t1.[from], t1.till, t1.costcentre, t1.rownumber, t1.percentage
FROM #ergebnis t1
WHERE
    [from] not in (select [from] from #concatenated t2 where t1.pernr = t2.pernr)
    and till not in (select till from #concatenated t2 where t1.pernr = t2.pernr);

-- Show the result
SELECT * FROM #concatenated2;
```

This will return a result, but not the expected one. The first statement returns only all rows with `RowNumber == 3`. In the second statement, the 3 rows will be squashed together leaving no space for the first and second row of each block.

Is there a way to properly combine the time spans? - I'm using SQL Server 2014 Standard edition, so things like PIVOT and PARTITION do work.

Comment: What do you mean by combining data? I don't see what you mean here. Also, is it normal to have dates from: 2015-12-10 Until 2015-12-09?

Comment: What happens to the dates like 2015-12-07, 08, 09? Why are they excluded from the result? what is the logic for From = 2015-12-10 with a Till **before** that date? (2015-12-09). Are you certain that result represents "*properly combined the time spans*"? They do not look proper to me at all.

Comment: When doing a group by, an easy way to avoid mistakes is to follow the general group by rule: "If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function." I.e. the selected columns that are not arguments to set functions are supposed to be the ones listed in the group by clause.

Comment: @jarlh I don't think there is anything wrong with the group by. I think the problem is the first select statement, which apparently gives the wrong results.

Comment: @SSIS2013,  I suppose you're right. (Must have misread...)

Comment: What is wrong with this query as a solution: 
SELECT PerNr, Name, MIN([FROM]) AS [FROM] ,MAX(Till) AS Till, CostCentre, RowNumber, Percentage
FROM #result
GROUP BY PerNr, Name, CostCentre,RowNumber,Percentage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT PerNr, Name, MIN([FROM]) AS [FROM] ,MAX(Till) AS Till, CostCentre, RowNumber, Percentage
FROM #result
GROUP BY PerNr, Name, CostCentre,RowNumber,Percentage
```

Comment: I tried it with a larger result set and it seems to be working. Thanks